# can we store multiple data on single id in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following.

```
id name 
1  Dhiraj Dhanaji Desai.
2  ram patil
3  aman mehta
```

I want this.

```
id name 
1  Dhiraj Dhanaji Desai.
   ram patil
   aman mehta
```

Comment: can you being more specific?

Comment: use `json` OR `Comma separated`

Comment: This looks like a really bad idea - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @P.Salmon sometime save json in a db it's a nice idea. Depends what you need

Comment: i want to store family data on single id.because when i want to fetch data this all data display on single id.

Comment: The short answer is you can store whatever you like in a char column. BUT does it make sense - how would you establish relationships between named individuals - spouse, parent,grand parent, child, sibling, cousin etc. And such design issues are outside the scope of this site so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `JSON` value in a field for having "multiple" data in a single field.

for example, you can store this value:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Dhiraj Dhanaji Desai"}
```

and get it back parsing JSON. (for example php have a function `json_decode`)

references:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
>
> https://www.json.org

Comment: It should be borne in mind that this can be helpful, but if you need to join on any sub-records, you may come unstuck. Only do this if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @andreah you could at least qualify your answer by stating json is available from As of MySQL 5.7.8, and confirming the op's version number.